# When to use custom directive vs ui-view vs ng-include in an AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building a large, complex AngularJS application (think ERP system). I am having a hard time deciding when it is appropriate to use `ui-view`, `ng-include` or a `custom directive + templateURL`.

I will give a few concrete examples to give y'all something to work with.

- A navigation menu that is used across all URLs of the application but includes a complex AJAX autosuggest/dropdown search box.
- A simple HTML footer that is the same across all URLs of the application
- The content areas that go in between the header and footer.
- The individual components that are nestled within the content area (such as and "Edit Profile" form, or user dashboard)
- Modal dialogs

**What are the best practices?**

Comment: Did you ever get good answers / reach you own conclusions?  I'm strugggling with exactly same situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any large or complex application, I would suggest organizing as much of your code into re-usable custom directives as possible.  Custom directives will allow you to leverage angular directives for maximum re-usability and minimize the repetitive HTML that exists when you rely only on built-in directives.

UI views are appropriate for swapping out controllers and views dynamically depending on the route. If you have application functionality where each view and controller combination is self-contained, then using a ui-view with routes makes sense.